# JQuery or Javascript to get element of window parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could someone help me with this? 
I have a page sitting in an iframe in a window, to be more specific it is the SharePoint dialog box.
I want to find an element with a specific id (or class, it doesn't matter) on the parent, not the window, where the popup originated.

I have tried

```
$(this).closest('.refreshbtn').click();
$(this).parents('.refreshbtn').click();
$(this).parent().parent().parent('.refreshbtn').click();
```

Tried it with javascript

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('refreshbtn').click();
window.parent.parent.document.getElementById('refreshbtn').click();
```

Without success.

Can someone shed some light?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It is true, thanks Barmer, it has been answered but I got it working just before viewing it... window.parent.document.getElementById was working but as I had set the ID of the element in question on page load the element lost the id when clicked. So here is my updated code: var refreshimg = window.parent.document.getElementById('ManualRefresh'); $(refreshimg).parent().closest('a').click();

Answer (score 1):

try this in the iFrame

```
$('#refreshbtn', window.parent.document).on('click', function(){
//do something
}
```

or assign it to a variable

```
var button = $('#refreshbtn', window.parent.document);
```